# Tensorflow isn't returning as expected for simple dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am completely new to tensorflow and learning it by following this series of video tutorials by google.

[Natural Language Processing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNxaJsNG3-s&list=PLQY2H8rRoyvzDbLUZkbudP-MFQZwNmU4S&index=1)

Was able to follow and made a simple program that is meant to learn a very short set of simple sentences with ratios assigned to them. Everything is highliy simplified so I can get an introductory understanding of tensorflow process.

But the result looks odd to me. Please refer to the code and its result below (sorry, the code base is a bit lengthy, but it is mostly basic processing given the tutorial). I gave just obvious things for learning. All are about revenue and when "high", the ratio is positive, and when "low" negative. But the result says positive 0.5 for both "high" and "low" sentences.

Can someone enlighten me here about what's wrong?

Thank you.

```
# dependencies
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

# raw data to learn
data_to_learn = [['revenue is high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is low', -0.4],
                 ['revenue is quite high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is quite low', -0.4],
                 ['revenue is slighly high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is slighly low', -0.4],
                 ['revenue is somewhat high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is somewhat low', -0.4],
                 ['revenue is very high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is very low', -0.4],
                 ['revenue is okay high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is okay low', -0.4],
                 ['revenue is commonly high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is commonly low', -0.4],
                 ['revenue is greatly high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is greatly low', -0.4],
                 ['revenue is super high', 0.4],
                 ['revenue is super low', -0.4]]              

# extracts components from data
sentences_to_learn = list(map(lambda x: x[0], data_to_learn))
labels_to_learn = list(map(lambda x: x[1], data_to_learn))

# data to test
sentences_to_test = ['revenue is very high', 
                     'revenue is low']

# tokenization
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000, 
                      oov_token="<OOV>")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences_to_learn)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

# sequencing
sequences_to_learn = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences_to_learn)
padded_to_learn = pad_sequences(sequences_to_learn, 
                                maxlen=20, 
                                padding='post',
                                truncating='post')
sequences_to_teset = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences_to_test)
padded_to_test = pad_sequences(sequences_to_teset, 
                               maxlen=20,
                               padding='post', 
                               truncating='post')

# convert to array (for tensorflow 2)
import numpy as np
padded_to_learn = np.array(padded_to_learn)
labels_to_learn = np.array(labels_to_learn)
padded_to_test = np.array(padded_to_test)

# modeling
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16, 
                              input_length=20),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# result
print(model.predict(padded_to_test))

# [[0.49741027]  ## Not as expected
#  [0.49763462]] ## Not as expected
# 2022-01-16 10:57:16.346374: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers
# /custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:112] 
# Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
```

Comment: Hi boingo, you havn't train your model yet, only compiled. So your are predicting with an untrained model and get a probability of roughly 0.5 , hence its like guessing

Comment: + you are not working with binary labels..

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this piece of code as given [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/TensorFlow%20In%20Practice/Course%203%20-%20NLP/Course%203%20-%20Week%202%20-%20Lesson%202.ipynb#scrollTo=0eJSTTYnkJQd).

Here are the points to improve your current code :

1. The dataset should be divided into a training and testing set first in a  suitable proportion (Ex. 80-20 split). You can directly split the dataset instead of separately defining the testing set, to avoid errors.
2. Sentences to test has been defined but the labels to test have not been defined.
3. You want to do a binary classification on the dataset you have created. Hence the classes should be labelled as 0 or 1 such as  {0.4:0 , -0.4 : 1} or vice versa.
4. The model.fit() function is missing. Hence the model is not actually learning the pattern of the training data.
5. For predictions, the data provided is not unseen.

Please refer to the latest code reference for text classification [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification#export_the_model)